# How to show all items on click of button in rich:autoComplete?

Tags: jsf-2, autocomplete, combobox, richfaces

Richfaces 4: 
I am using rich:autoComplete with atribute showButton as "true" as shown below:

```
<rich:autocomplete mode="client" value="#{backingBean.selectedType}"
  autocompleteList= "#{backingBean.availableTypes}" 
  showButton="true">
</rich:autocomplete>
```

Currently, it shows filtered values as user types something as suggestions. Also, on click of button it shows filtered values only.

I need to show full list of available types irrespective of whatever user has entered in textBox on click of button. But, typing in textbox should filter the results. This behavior was earlier present in richfaces 3.3 combobox but somehow, in Richfaces 4, it seems to be missing.

Does anyone has idea about how to achieve this, please?

Comment: Do you have any findings regarding this issue or is this still unsolved for you?

Comment: I am unable to use rich:autoComplete for this purpose. I have used jQuery combobox instead. http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old question, and I think RF 4.5.2 will have an option for better behavior, but *if* someone finds themselves facing this in RF 4.3, we were able to fix this by modifying AutoComplete.js in richfaces-components-ui-4.3.7.Final.jar:

```
rf.getDomElement(this.fieldId).focus();
if (this.isVisible) {
    this.__hide(event);
} else {
    var newItems = this.cache.getItems('', this.options.filterFunction);
    this.items = $(newItems);
    $(rf.getDomElement(this.id + 'Items')).empty().append(this.items);
    onShow.call(this, event);
}
```

The first three lines of the else clause are new and cause the whole list to appear when the dropdown button is clicked. Otherwise the component filtering works the same. (This is with client mode. I haven't tried with other options.)

I had trouble building the project from source, but for this all that was needed was to unzip the jar file, replace the js, and re-jar it.